# При выводе односвязного списка выводятся одинаковые элементы

Tags: c++, список, списки

Есть код, который позволяет добавлять объект (многочлен) в список

```
    void List::add(Polynom &polynom)
{
    Polynom *temp = new Polynom(); // Выделяем память под новый объект 
    temp->Next = HEAD; // меняем адрес начала списка 

    temp->degree = polynom.degree;
    temp->coefficient = polynom.coefficient;
    cout << *temp; // покажем что записалось

    size++; // увеличиваем переменную хранящую размер на 1
    HEAD = temp; // меняем адрес начала списка
}
```

Есть функция вывода всех добавленных объектов в список

```
void List::show()
{
    Polynom *temp = HEAD; // объявляем указатель и пусть он указывает на начало списка
    int i = 0;

    while (temp != NULL) // пока есть на что указывать
    {
        cout << i << " полином: ";
        cout << *temp;
        cout << endl << endl;

        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->Next;
        i++;
    }
}
```

Но почему-то, если в главной функции добавить несколько (n) многочленов, а потом попросить вывести их, то список выведет n одинаковых многочленов, которые равны последнему введенному.

```
List list;

                Polynom poly;
                cout << "Введите количество вводимых многочленов >> ";
                int n;
                cin >> n;
                cout << "\nВведите степень многочленов >> ";
                cin >> degree;
                poly.setDegree(degree);

                for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                {
                    cout << "\n Введите " << i << " многочлен\n";
                    cin >> poly;
                    list.add(poly);
                    cout << endl;
                }
                list.show();
```

[image: Вот как это выглядит]

Я так понимаю, ошибка крутится где-то на выводе, потому что ввод, кажется, верный. Указатели скачут и все многочлены в одно место не записываются. Укажите пожалуйста на ошибку.

### #

Ошибка была в воде массива коэффициентов:
изменил `temp->coefficient = polynom.coefficient;`

на это

```
`for (int i = 0; i <= polynom.getDegree(); i++)
        temp->coefficient[i] = polynom.coefficient[i];
```

Comment: Вы чтобы локализовать проблему встаньте дебагом на окончание ВВОДА и посмотрите -правильно ли там заполнена структура.

Comment: То что вы выводите temp совсем не значит что в в списке он встал на нужное место. Вывод одного полинома ничего не говорит о корректном формировании списка.

Comment: @Mira Спасибо за дебаг) Как оказалось, я неправильно заносил значения в массив коэффициентов. Продебажил ввод, как вы сказали, и понял что туда заносится не совсем то, что нужно) Поменял код и все работает верно:)

Comment: изменил это `temp->coefficient = polynom.coefficient;` на вот это

`for (int i = 0; i <= polynom.getDegree(); i++)
  temp->coefficient[i] = polynom.coefficient[i]; `

Comment: Рада что помогло :) ! Оформите свое решение как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в неправильном вводе массива коэффициентов:

необходимо изменить `temp->coefficient = polynom.coefficient;`

на это

```
for (int i = 0; i <= polynom.getDegree(); i++)
        temp->coefficient[i] = polynom.coefficient[i];
```